# Model Stacking and tuning a meta-model - CV strategy?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, ensemble-learning, stacking, h2o

I was hoping some of the more experienced ensemblers could help me with a couple of questions I have regarding stacking.

The assumption is that we have a classic `train`/`test` split, the goal is maximal `test` performance, and that we don't know whether stacking will be beneficial right from the start (so want to avoid partitioning `train` further, thus the CV-based stacking approach).

Here is my understanding steps used in stacking:

1. Fix the fold indices at the start for `train`, e.g. using `sklearn.model_selection.KFold` in `Python` or `caret::createFolds` in `R` (e.g. we are using 5-fold CV - call this split **`fixed_5_folds`**)
2. Build some tuned (first level) models using cross-validation (tuned using **`fixed_5_folds`**):
   `M1`, `M2`, `M3`
3. Take these tuned models and generate your out-of-fold predictions (meta-features) for the training dataset (using **`fixed_5_folds`**?):

   `meta_features_train = [META_M1_train, META_M2_train, META_M3_train]`
4. Re-fit models `M1`, `M2` and `M3` on the full `train` dataset (excluding the meta-features), predict for the `test` data to generate the equivalent meta-features for the `test` data:

   `meta_features_test = [META_M1_test, META_M2_test, META_M3_test]`
5. Tune a meta-model (second level) on `meta_features_train`, using cross-validation to tune its hyper-parameters (using using **`fixed_5_folds`**?)
6. Re-fit this tuned meta-model to the full `meta_features_train` dataset, predict for `meta_features_test`
7. These predictions on `meta_features_test` are your final predictions

I have two main questions here:

1. Is my understanding of the stacking process correct?
2. Is it necessary/good/bad to use the *exact same folds split* throughout the entire analysis? E.g:

   **a)** Using different CV folds to generate the OOF predictions/meta-features in step 3, e.g. let's say I use a different split of 20 folds instead to generate my training OOF meta-features (**Possible advantage:** More data will be used to generate your meta-features)

   **b)** Using different CV folds to tune the meta-model in step 5, e.g. let's say I settle on Ridge Regression as the meta-model and the small number of meta-features means training is very fast, so I decide to instead use 3 repeats of 10-fold CV to tune this meta-model (**Possible advantage:** same reason repeated CV is used generally - reducing the variability of the meta-model CV estimates, allowing better hyper-parameter selection)

   **c)** **Possible disadvantage:** Varying the folds used could be introducing some sort of leakage that I'm not aware of

For point **b)** above, it seems like varying the folds seems to have been used by some well-known kaggle competitors, e.g. Giba in his [1st place solution here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/discussion/14335), although he goes from using 5 folds at the first level to 4 folds at the second level (the point being that his folds don't appear to be fixed between levels 1 and 2).

Hopefully you guys can help!